# Mean Average Precision (MAP)

Tags: image-processing, cbir

I am using Mean Average Precision (MAP) to evaluate the performance of a Content Based Image Retrieval System.
As shown in the figure, it is the average of the precision of queries.
[image]

In my database I have 200 images containing 4 categories, 50 images per category, I want to make retrieval with 4 queries (from each category, one query) , Can I calculate the MAP only for the TOP 10 images retrieved? Or I am obliged to calculate it for the 50 relevant images?